# Python Socket and Native Android App Wi-fi communication

Tags: python, android, sockets, networking, raspberry-pi

Thanks that you have opened my question, perhaps you know the answer ;) Let's move to the issue.

Basically, I am developing a project(I won't go into details about this) that consists of Raspberry Pi Zero(**Server**) and Native Android App(**Client**). My objective is to create an automatic Wi-fi communication between them in the local network. Generally, on the RP(Raspberry PI) the Python socket is running with the assigned port. So, I want to create TCP socket connection using Android App. BUT for that, I need an IP address and port where this "socket is running". So it means that I have to hardcode this information in the Android App, don't I? So it means, that if I change the network, IP address of RP will be different and I won't be able to connect to that. But I want to avoid that so that it can find & connect to the server automatically.

The first thing which comes up is:

1. Set up hostname for the Server e.g MyRP
2. In the Android App -> get IP by host name -> create TCP socket connection.
   But I am not sure if it is right.

The second thing is: set up static IP for the server and keep the IP in the Android App-> I am also not sure if this is the right and good way.

I also found something like [NSD](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd) for Android, but I haven't investigated it thoroughly.

I really hope you got my idea(if not, just tell me -> I will write more information) and hope you can suggest to me some approaches... I am not good at networking stuff like DNS etc... therefore I really need your help

Comment: `So it means that I have to hardcode this information in the Android App, don't I?` No. Your client knows the used port and it can determine its own local lan ip. Say it is 192.168.1.13. Make a routine for the client where you try in a loop to connect to 192.168.1.##:<port>. Where ## runs from 2 to say 33. Set a time out of one second. Within seconds the client finds the right ip.

Comment: @blackapps So, If I have the range from 0 to 255 possible IPs in my network -> the maximum time to find the target device would be 255 seconds? I have seen some application, for example, SmartHome etc... that actually looks for their devices in the local network very fast.... I would like to know how they implemented that :(

Comment: In practice you would find the server within seconds i said. How much clients in your network? Three? Five? More? If your client has nr 13 then the raspi probably has number 14. Its time you try this.

Comment: @blackapps yes, agree with you. However, there can be some cases when the LAN has a lot of devices. Anyway, let me try this approach and we will see ;)